# when Ι write a data frame to CSV file some char are stored like \"\"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgUYh.png)  is the image of csv file.

```
val df = Seq((0l, "East", "100", " "),
      (1l, "West", "200", " "),
      (2l, "East", "500", " "),
      (7l, "West", "2090", " ")
    ).toDF("__zsid", "Region", "Sales", "Cost")

    df.write.format("csv").save(filePath)
```

Comment: please provide some more details. The source code where you actually write to the file would be a nice start

Comment: val df = Seq((0l, "East", "100", " "),
      (1l, "West", "200", " "),
      (2l, "East", "500", " "),
      (7l, "West", "2090", " ")
    ).toDF("__zsid", "Region", "Sales", "Cost")

    df.write.format("csv").save(filePath)

Comment: please add the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `null` instead of an empty string.

In addition, you can try one of these options:

```
df.write.option("quote", "\u0000").format("csv").save(filePath)

df.write.options("quoteAll", "false").format("csv").save(filePath)
```